# How to compare numbers with decimal point and logical OR operation?

Tags: conditionals, comparison

I'm reading five values from external CSV file as [`\sone`, `\stwo`, `\sthree`, `\sfour`, `\sfive`]. Sample values could be [55.3, 89.0, 33.5, 40, 0.10].

**Question :**

1. How to compare number with decimal points. For example, I can compare numbers using `\ifnum\sone=1`, but it does not accept decimal point.
2. How to apply logical **OR** condition for printing respective statements? For example,

   > IF `\sone` > 70.4 **OR** `\stwo` > 80.33 **OR** `\sthree` <= 33.0 **OR** `\sfour` = 80 **OR** `\sfive` >= 0.11 THEN
   >     Print this line
   >   ELSE Print other line
   >   END IF

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "traditional" way is the old-school way. That is, you convert the numbers into lengths/dimensions (that can contain decimal values, like `2.5pt`) and perform the comparison using `\ifdim` rather than `\ifnum`.

Logical operations like **OR** and **AND** are performed using the basic `\if...<true>\else<false>\fi` structure, mixing and match as required to obtain the required output. For example, logical **OR** could be

```
\if...<true>\else\if...<true>\fi\fi
```

while logical **AND** could be

```
\if...\if...<true>\fi\fi
```

Here is an example that addresses your question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\sone{55.3}
\def\stwo{89.0}
\def\sthree{33.5}
\def\sfour{40}
\def\sfive{0.10}
\begin{document}

two \ifdim\stwo pt<\sthree pt $<$\else $\geq$\fi{} three \par
five \ifdim\sfive pt<\sfour pt $<$\else $\geq$\fi{} four \par

\newif\ifcondition\conditionfalse

\ifdim\sone pt>70.4pt A\conditiontrue\else
\ifdim\stwo pt>80.33pt B\conditiontrue\else
\ifdim\sthree pt<33.0pt C\conditiontrue\else
\ifdim\sthree pt=33.0pt D\conditiontrue\else
\ifdim\sfour pt=80pt E\conditiontrue\else
\ifdim\sfive pt>0.11pt F\conditiontrue\else
\ifdim\sfive pt=0.11pt G\conditiontrue%\else
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi

\ifcondition thisline\else otherline\fi

\end{document}
```

To avoid great duplication in the last clause, I've created a boolean `\ifcondition` and set it to true - `\conditiontrue` - if any one of the cases are met. Otherwise it remains false - `\conditionfalse`. I've additionally included where the condition is met with the nested string of conditionals.

---

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) "simplifies" this input greatly with the ability to mix logical operators as needed using `\ifboolexpr{<expression>}{<true>}{<false>}`. The above MWE is replicated using the `etoolbox` boolean expression syntax below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\def\sone{55.3}
\def\stwo{89.0}
\def\sthree{33.5}
\def\sfour{40.0}
\def\sfive{0.1}
\begin{document}

two
\ifboolexpr{
  test {\ifdimless{\stwo pt}{\sthree pt}}
}
{$<$} % true
{$\geq$} % false
three

five
\ifboolexpr{
  test {\ifdimless{\sfive pt}{\sfour pt}}
}
{$<$} % true
{$\geq$} % false
four

\ifboolexpr{
  test {\ifdimgreater{\sone pt}{70.4pt}} or
  test {\ifdimgreater{\stwo pt}{80.33pt}} or
  (test {\ifdimless{\sthree pt}{33.0pt}} or test {\ifdimequal{\sthree pt}{33.0pt}}) or
  test {\ifdimequal{\sfour pt}{80pt}} or
  (test {\ifdimgreater{\sfive pt}{0.11pt}} or test {\ifdimequal{\sfive pt}{0.11pt}})
}
{thisline} % true
{otherline} % false

\end{document}
```

`test {<bool expression>}` is used to evaluate any boolean expression other than the basic TeX `\if`-conditionals, and grouping/nesting is allowed. Read more about these tests in sections **3.6.4 Arithmetic Tests** and **3.6.5 Boolean Expressions** (p 18-23) of the [`etoolbox` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf).

<sub>`etoolbox`, by the way, should be in every LaTeX-user's toolkit.</sub>

---

If your numbers all have the same structure, say `XXX.XX`, then you can also use pdfTeX's `\pdfstrcmp{<string1>}{<string2>}`. This command compares two strings and expands to 0 if the strings are equal (`<string1> = <string2>`), to -1 if the first string ranks before the second (`<string1> < <string2>`), and to 1 otherwise (`<string1> > <string2>`). The primitive was introduced in pdfTEX 1.30.0.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\sone{55.3}
\def\stwo{89.0}
\def\sthree{33.5}
\def\sfour{40.0}
\def\sfive{00.1}
\begin{document}

\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\stwo}{\sthree}=-1 two $<$ three \else two $\geq$ three\fi \par
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\sfive}{\sfour}=-1 five $<$ four \else five $\geq$ four\fi \par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. I've learnt a lot from your post. Now, I'm able to compare required numbers.

Comment: @Werner 
Quote: logical OR could be ·\if...<true>\else\if...<true>\fi\fi· end quote. You see, the <true> part has to be written twice. It would be annoying especially when the content of <true> part is large and complex. Is there a way to write <true> part only once in logical OR with Tex primitives as it does in logical AND you give?

Comment: @lyl: There is. You could define a new boolean which you set in the `<true>` parts, and then condition on that at a later stage (after the nested `\if`s).

Comment: @Werner You mean replacing the two <true> parts in `\if...<true>\else\if...<true>\fi\fi` with the two new booleans?

Comment: @lyl: Try [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/zEb2xgia) using `\newif`. Also see [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/H7tX9D6q) that uses [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) operations. There are similar options using `and`.

Comment: @Werner Many thanks!! I got it.

Answer (score 8):

You can compare numerical quantities (with decimal points, scientific notation or fractions) and combine numerical conditions using [xintfrac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint), and, for easier input syntax [xintexpr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint).

Updated as [xintexpr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) has been expanded since original answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintexpr}% version 1.1 or later.

\begin{document}
\def\sone{55.3}
\def\stwo{89.0}
\def\sthree{33.5}
\def\sfour{40}
\def\sfive{0.10}


\xintifboolexpr {  \sone > 70.4  ||  \stwo > 80.33 || \sthree <= 33.0 || 
                     \sfour = 80 || \sfive >= 0.11 }
         {At least one of the inequalities is true}
         {None of the tested inequalities is true}

% Alternative syntax:

\xintifboolexpr {  \sone > 70.4  'or'  \stwo > 80.33 'or' \sthree <= 33.0 'or' 
                     \sfour = 80 'or' \sfive >= 0.11 }
         {At least one of the inequalities is true}
         {None of the tested inequalities is true}

\xintifboolexpr {any(\sone > 70.4, \stwo > 80.33 , \sthree <= 33.0,
                          \sfour = 80, \sfive >= 0.11)}
         {At least one of the inequalities is true}
         {None of the tested inequalities is true}

\xintifboolexpr { 3.5 > 3.4 'and' (-123 > -123.1 'or' -123 > -122.9) }
             {YES}
             {NO}

% equivalently

\xintifboolexpr { 3.5 > 3.4 && (-123 > -123.1 || -123 > -122.9)}
             {YES}
             {NO}

\end{document}
```

> [image: booleans]

Answer (score 8):

One can use `l3fp` facilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\booltest}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpcompare}{m}
 {
  \fp_compare_p:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\sone{55.3}
\def\stwo{89.0}
\def\sthree{33.5}
\def\sfour{40}
\def\sfive{0.10}

\booltest{
  \fpcompare{\sone > 0.74} || 
  \fpcompare{\stwo > 80.33} ||
  \fpcompare{\sthree <= 33.0} ||
  \fpcompare{\sfour = 80} ||
  \fpcompare{\sfive >= 0.11}
 }
 {Print this line}
 {Print this other line}

\def\sone{0.73}
\def\stwo{80}
\booltest{
  \fpcompare{\sone > 0.74} || 
  \fpcompare{\stwo > 80.33} ||
  \fpcompare{\sthree <= 33.0} ||
  \fpcompare{\sfour = 80} ||
  \fpcompare{\sfive >= 0.11}
 }
 {Print this line}
 {Print this other line}

\end{document}
```

This outputs

> Print this line
>   Print this other line

One can also use parentheses around subexpressions, the negation operator `!` and the and operator `&&`.

Comment: I would gladly upvote, but that would break the current draw in upvotes to your advantage ... ;-)

Comment: my count moved up, so I did upvote `l3fp`... can't do anything more now ;-)

Comment: @jfbu Now it's not a draw, as I upvoted yours.

Comment: molto bravo! grazie.

Answer (score 1):

If you already use `TikZ` (3.0.0+) you can use `math` library. But do not load `TikZ` just for this, the other answers are (probably) lighter and faster than this one.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
% define all constants
\def\sone{55.3}
\def\stwo{89.0}
\def\sthree{33.5}
\def\sfour{40}
\def\sfive{0.10}
% make a decision
\tikzmath{
  int \answer;
  if ( \sone > 70.4  ||  \stwo < 80.33 || \sthree*\sfive <= \sfour-35 ) then {
    \answer = 43*sin(\stwo);
    {The third inequality is true, so ...\newline};
  } else {
    \answer = 0;
    {This will not be printed.};
  };
}
% Output the result
the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is: \answer
\end{document}
```

[image]