# message error in biblatex.4ht with tex4ht, even with no bibliography

Tags: biblatex, tex4ht, html

I have the following message when I compile a document calling biblatex, whether I run `biber` or not, in order to create a `.bbl`. I use Biber 2.3.

My file is `% biblatex.4ht (2015-08-05-15:37), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex`

The `pdf` has no error during the compilation, only the tex4ht complains.

```
(/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/biblatex.4ht
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
.
l.158 \ifnum\blx:ver:no
                      < 3
?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
.
l.158 \ifnum\blx:ver:no
                      < 3
?
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
.
l.359 \ifnum\blx:ver:no
                      < 3
?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
.
l.359 \ifnum\blx:ver:no
                      < 3
```

the document is simple, since it has nothing in it.

i compile with `make4ht -ul hello.tex "fn-in"`

I use an extension of tex4ht by @michal.h21,

https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht

But I od not believe it influence anything since I do not activate it here.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\usepackage[backend=biber, language=british]{biblatex}


% \usepackage{alternative4ht}
%  \altusepackage{fontspec}
%  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
%%  \newfontfamily\greekfont{Linux Libertine O}
%%  \newfontfamily\russianfont{Linux Libertine O}
%%  \newfontfamily\hindifont{Siddhanta}
%  \altusepackage{polyglossia}
%  \setmainlanguage{french}
%%  \setotherlanguage{czech}
%%  \setotherlanguage{greek}
%%  \setotherlanguage{russian}
%%  \setotherlanguage{hindi} 




\begin{document}

cou

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, the problem is the line `\ifdefstring{\abx@version}{3.0}{\xdef\blx:ver:no{3}}{\xdef\blx:ver:no{2.9}}` since you have version 3.1 or 3.2 we don't get `\xdef\blx:ver:no{3}` (which we should get), but `\xdef\blx:ver:no{2.9}` which causes trouble when comparing numbers. That is definitely worth a bug report to the tex4ht people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version (`2015-08-05-15:37`) of `biblatex.4ht` in TeX live contains the line

```
\ifdefstring{\abx@version}{3.0}{\xdef\blx:ver:no{3}}{\xdef\blx:ver:no{2.9}}
```

Since you are running version 3.1 or 3.2 of `biblatex` (and thus not `3.0`), you get `\blx:ver:no` set to `2.9`.
But then `\ifnum` has trouble with non-integers, so everything goes pear-shaped.

You can fix the problem by replacing the line above with a simple

```
\xdef\blx:ver:no{3}
```

Comment: I would consider this a bug in tex4ht. The `ifdefstring{\abx@version}{3.0}` is too restrictive and `\ifnum` has troubles with decimals.

Comment: yes, it is a bug in `tex4ht`. what would you propose for proper testing the version? It needs to support also pre-3.0 versions

Comment: @michal.h21 I think you "only" need to check `\abx@version` against 3. I found [How to compare numbers with decimal point and logical OR operation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136501/35864) for decimal `\ifnum`, not sure if there is something better. Checking against a string, is probably a bit complicated to scale.

Comment: @michal.h21 Indeed, `\ifdim\abx@version pt < 3pt
  A
\else
  B
\fi` seems to work just fine. But again, there might be something better.

Comment: thanks, the  `\ifdim` solution is good, I will report that to tex4ht tracker

Comment: For those interested, the bug report is [#268](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?268)

Comment: @michal.h21 Sorry to be a pain in the buttocks, but I believe the proposed patch will still break things with `biblatex` versions `< 3`. The `\ifnum\blx:ver:no < 3` still can't handle `\blx:ver:no` being `2.9`. Why not simply cut the middleman and replace all `\ifnum\blx:ver:no < 3` by `ifdim\abx@version pt< 3pt` or save the result in a `\newif` and use that later?

Comment: thanks for spotting this, you are right. I think there is no reason to use `\xdef\blx:ver:no{2.9}`,  `\xdef\blx:ver:no{2}` should be just fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: @michal.h21 I expect that would work, yes. But I don't understand why you take this "detour" of rolling your own version information, when you could check against `\ifdim\abx@version pt< 3pt` all the time. Still, there is one problem I didn't think of before, version 2.9a has `\def\abx@version{2.9a}`, so can't be tested against as a dimension. Not sure what to do about this one ...